# List slicing, get last item if length of list is 1

Tags: python, list, slice

I am aware that if I do:

```
>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>> a[:-1]

Output:  [1,2,3]
```

But:

```
>> a = [1]
>> a[:-1]

Output:  []
```

Though in this case first is last and vice versa. How can I get to select the last item if the length of the list is 1?

Comment: And how are these two results irreconcilable. That slice gives all elements, but the last, which obviously works perfectly in both cases.

Comment: Well its more of selecting items in a list. The length of the list in my case constantly changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to handle the special case somehow. One way is use `max` and avoid using the negative indexing:

```
a[:max(1, len(a) - 1)]
```

You can also use short-circuiting:

```
a[:-1] or a[:]
```

Comment: It works! Would you be able to explain how removing the negative indexing works?

Comment: Wait I think I got it, it will never have to reach negative indexing that way. So a list with just 1 item will just be list[:1].

Comment: No magic, as you seem to have understood. Empty list and list of length 1 will be list[:1] and the rest list[:len-1].

Answer (score 5):

You could use a simple or ternary `if-else`:

```
slc = a[:] if len(a) == 1 else a[:-1]
```

Comment: That doesn't result in "the last item" but in a list containing it (if there is one).

Comment: Nice an elegant. Just change the last slicing, the author asked to get always the last element so it needs to be `a[-1:]`

Comment: @Vinny that's what he gets. I still think: `slc = a[:-1] if len(a) != 1 else a[:]` is a more clear syntax (it is a exact copy)

Comment: running this code on my py2.7, on a list [1, 2, 3] results with [1, 2] because `a[:-1]` means give me all elements BUT the last.

Comment: @Vinny And isn't that what OP wants? Reading it again you got a point, the question is not very clear but I still believe this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[-1:]** means give me the last element in the list. You can use `or` statement, and it will get you the value:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]
v = ls[-1:] or ls[:]
v
[3]

ls = [1]
v = ls[-1:] or ls[:]
v
[1]
```

This works for both cases, when the list has one or more elements.

Comment: This could raise an exception for empty lists.

Comment: I've updated my answer. This works for all cases (if the list is empty, has 1 element or more) and now it doesn't throw an exception in case of empty list.

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense. You only get to `ls[:]` if `ls` is empty, and then `ls[:]` is *the same* as `ls[-1:]`.